# Remove duplicates from array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, class, duplicates

I have a class called `Customer` that has several string properties like

```
firstName, lastName, email, etc.
```

I read in the customer information from a `csv` file that creates an array of the class:

```
Customer[] customers
```

I need to *remove the duplicate customers having the same email address*, leaving only 1 customer record for each particular email address.

I have done this using 2 loops but it takes nearly 5 minutes as there are usually 50,000+ customer records.  Once I am done removing the duplicates, I need to write the customer information to another csv file (no help needed here).

If I did a `Distinct` in a loop how would I remove the other string variables that are a part of the class for that particular customer as well?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Is the idea to run this daily/weekly/quarterly? Frequency of this task will likely dictate the permanence of a solution.

Comment: Distinct will not work for custom types without using new equality comparer. use DistinctBy from MoreLinq. btw this operation will not take much time for 50k items since distinct is `O(n)`

Comment: My choice would probably be to sort the input file by duplicate key (email in your case) and do a simple previous to current value comparison before adding to your object.

Comment: I'd use a `KeyedCollection` (in `System.Collectons.ObjectModell`). Let the eMail be the Key and insert after checking with `Contains`. This is very fast...

Comment: Possibly related / helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537823/distinct-by-property-of-class-by-linq

Comment: What do you mean "I have done this using 2 loops" ?

Comment: When you find a duplicate, how will decide which record to keep, bearing in mind that both records might not have the same data in all of the fields?

Comment: This will be run daily.  To use the loops I have the outer loop set to cycle through the array of customers, each time grabbing the current customer email, then an inner loop to run back through all of the customers checking the email addresses, if they are found to have a duplicate, I set a boolean field on the matching customer to mark for deletion.  I don't actually delete the customer entry, when I write to the file I check to see if this boolean is true or not first to determine if I should write or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `Linq`, you can do this in O(n) time (single level loop) with a `GroupBy`

```
var uniquePersons = persons.GroupBy(p => p.Email)
                           .Select(grp => grp.First())
                           .ToArray();
```

**Update**

A bit on `O(n)` behavior of `GroupBy`.

`GroupBy` is implemented in `Linq` (`Enumerable.cs`) as this -

The `IEnumerable` is iterated only once to create the grouping. A `Hash` of the key provided (e.g. "Email" here) is used to find unique keys, and the elements are added in the `Grouping` corresponding to the keys.

Please see this [GetGrouping](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,57b0aa9f1c572776) code. And some old posts for reference.

- [What's the asymptotic complexity of GroupBy operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889669/whats-the-asymptotic-complexity-of-groupby-operation)
- [What guarantees are there on the run-time complexity (Big-O) of LINQ methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods)

Then `Select` is obviously an O(n) code, making the above code `O(n)` overall.

**Update 2**

To handle `empty`/`null` values.

So, if there are instances where the value of `Email` is `null` or `empty`, the simple `GroupBy` will take just one of those objects from `null` & `empty` each.

One quick way to include all those objects with `null`/`empty` value is to use some unique keys at the run time for those objects, like

```
var tempEmailIndex = 0;
var uniqueNullAndEmpty = persons
                         .GroupBy(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Email) 
                                       ? (++tempEmailIndex).ToString() : p.Email)
                         .Select(grp => grp.First())
                         .ToArray();
```

Comment: *"As Linq is using Reflection"* - do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Shnugo - LINQ doesn't use reflection.

Comment: Can you please tell us how you know that this will execute in O(n) ?

Comment: This is working extremely well, but for some reason it is not writing anything to the csv file now.  I see that after deleting the duplicates it returns the new array of customers and has data in it, and I have not changed an of the code that writes to the file...

Comment: nvm, had to pass in the count of the customer records when creating a new Customer array.

Comment: @AWooster seems like you have solved the csv creation problem, good to know it helped :)

Comment: @MikeNakis - It's `O(n)` because it only has to iterate the list once to build the groups.

Comment: @Enigmativity this is not really an explanation, because in building the groups it is going to have to use a target data structure to add the groups to, so the running time depends on the time complexity of a) checking for existence and b) adding to that data structure.  I have thought about it, and the explanation is that the data structure that will be used will probably be a hash set, which is O(1), so the total combined time is O(2N), which is O(N).  What bugs me is that Arghya did not bother to answer.

Comment: @MikeNakis please see I had updated the answer with explanation and references.

Comment: @ArghyaC 
 
In my testing I have found (obviously) that this is removing customers that do not have an email address associated, is there an easy way to exclude this? If not, I will assign a random number to the customers email address field when there is nothing present. Thanks.

Comment: @AWooster see if the **update 2** solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
public class Person {
    public Person(string eMail, string Name) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class eMailKeyedCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string, Person> {
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Person item) {
        return item.eMail;
    }
}

public void testIt() {
    var testArr = new Person[5];
    testArr[0] = new Person("Jon@Mullen.com", "Jon Mullen");
    testArr[1] = new Person("Jane@Cullen.com", "Jane Cullen");
    testArr[2] = new Person("Jon@Cullen.com", "Jon Cullen");
    testArr[3] = new Person("John@Mullen.com", "John Mullen");
    testArr[4] = new Person("Jon@Mullen.com", "Test Other"); //same eMail as index 0...

    var targetList = new eMailKeyedCollection();
    foreach (var p in testArr) {
        if (!targetList.Contains(p.eMail))
            targetList.Add(p);
    }
}
```

If the item is found in the collection, you could easily pick (and eventually modify) it with:

```
        if (!targetList.Contains(p.eMail))
            targetList.Add(p);
        else {
           var currentPerson=targetList[p.eMail];
           //modify Name, Address whatever... 
        }
```