# Swift removing duplicate from array of object

Tags: ios, json, swift3, nsarray, nsdictionary

I try to append json data that I got from my server to array of object and want to remove any duplicate if there is any

this is my custom class

```
class datastruct {

    var id: Int?
    var name: String?

    init(add: NSDictionary) {
        id = add["id"] as? Int
        name = add["name"] as? String
    }
}
```

and this is my code that I use to append json to my array

```
    var data:Array< datastruct > = Array < datastruct >()
    Alamofire.request(url)
                .responseJSON{ response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let JSON):
                        if let list = JSON as? NSArray {
                            for i in 0 ..< list.count {
                                if let res = list[i] as? NSDictionary {
                                    self.data.append(datastruct(add: res))
                                }
                            }
                            self.refresh()
                        }

                    case .failure(let error):

                    }

                }
```

the problem is I already search several solution to remove any duplicate array in stackoverflow

[Remove duplicate objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709066/remove-duplicate-objects-in-an-array)

[Remove duplicates from array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142463/remove-duplicates-from-array-of-objects)

[Removing Duplicates From Array of Custom Objects Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307188/removing-duplicates-from-array-of-custom-objects-swift)

but I when I try to use `Hashable` I don't know where to put `Set` to my code because it is `NSDictionary`

Please help me how to remove duplicate of array or give me some hint

Comment: conform your class `Datastruct`  with `Equatable` protocol. look SO for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is easier way to solve this problem.
First your `datastruct` class should be extend `NSObject`. 
Then Add `isEqual(_ object: Any?)` method in your `datastruct`. like this way.

```
class datastruct : NSObject {

    var id: Int?
    var name: String?

    init(add: NSDictionary) {
        id = add["id"] as? Int
        name = add["name"] as? String
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        let obj = object as! datastruct
        if self.id == obj.id {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }   
}
```

Now you can check for duplication.

```
if let res = list[i] as? NSDictionary {
    let dataStructObj =  datastruct(add: res)
    if !data.contains(dataStructObj) {
        self.data.append(dataStructObj)
    }

}
```

I hope it will help you.